# get row from range in current worksheet?

Tags: excel, office-js

I can not get tables name in active worksheet. I have a drop-down that will be populated with worksheets in workbook. I have another drop-down that should get all columns names(header) in selected worksheets. Somehow range.address has "sheet1!2:2" .

Here is code that I used:

```js
function getRow(worksheetName) {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
            // Queue a command to write the sample data to the worksheet
            // at moment i have only one worksheet named "Sheet1"

            var range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(worksheetName).getRange().getRow(1);
            range.load('address');
            // Run the queued-up commands, and return a promise to indicate task 
            //completion
            return ctx.sync().then(function () {
                console.log(range.address); // prints Sheet1!2:2
            })
        })
        .catch(errorHandler);
}
```

Here is a [link to spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1352uNtVhYBZG1vTEVQYmgwcFE) that I used for testing.

Any clue what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure there are tables on the worksheet? From your screenshot, it looks like you have a populated range, but its not possible to tell if you've created a table for that range. Not every range, including ranges with data, are tables. A table has to be created, either by the user through the UI or programmatically.

Comment: @RickKirkham sorry you are absolutely right, I just got confused I thought spreadsheet should have a table by default,but apparently user has to create this table. I updated question. Thank you again

Comment: @kero -- I notice that you've edited this question such that it's now an entirely different question than the one you asked originally (and that I answered below). In the future, please submit a *new* question in this scenario (i.e., if your original question has already been answered and your new question is altogether different from the question you originally asked). Doing so will prevent other people from being confused (by the answer not matching the question) when reading through this Q/A thread in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you replace `getRange()` with `getUsedRange()` instead, as shown here:

```
function getRow(worksheetName) {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
            var range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(worksheetName).getUsedRange().getRow(1);
            range.load('address');

            return ctx.sync().then(function () {
                console.log(range.address); 
            })
        })
        .catch(errorHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rick Kirkham's comment above is correct.  In the file that you've linked to, there is no **table** object -- although the worksheet does contain several rows/columns of data, that data is not explicitly contained inside a **table**.

Are you able to manually manipulate this file? If yes, then you can create a table object for the data by doing the following:

1. Select the data you want to be in the table.
2. With that data selected, choose the **Table** button (on the **Insert** tab).
3. Verify inputs in the **Create Table** prompt and choose **OK**.

If you are not able to manually manipulate this file, then you can create the table (from the range of data in your worksheet) by using the Office JavaScript API, as described here: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-tables#convert-a-range-to-a-table.

Comment: I updated question sorry for confusion, I thought spreadsheet should has a giant table hold data by default, but apparently not

Comment: Please see my additional answer below (which addresses your new/updated question).